# How to run a script from another path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I am creating a nodejs package and within the program, a bash script is executed.
The bash script "./helpers/script.sh" should be executed via a relative path, which means when i install the package and run it, the script should be loaded from 'appdata/roaming/npm/mypackage/helpers/script.sh' and not the current working directory.

I have tried using path.relative() and path.resolve() but with no help because it keeps trying to find the script file in my CWD.

```
exec(`bash ./helpers/init.sh`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error === null) {
    console.log('Done.')
    // do something
  } else {
    console.log(error)
  }
})
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please share part of the code where you are calling shell script so we can help

Comment: Sorry, updated now

Comment: If you try to call `init.sh` from `script.sh` & you specified the path of the `script.sh` correctly, then the command `bash ./helpers/init.sh` is wrong and should be `bash ./init.sh` instead in the first place

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly and you are trying to call `init.sh` from `script.sh` located in the same directory, then, I'd try the following:

```js
// script.sh
const path = require('path');

const initAbsPath = path.resolve('./init.sh');

exec(`bash ${initAbsPath}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  // ...
});
```